# Filling missing values by a grouping ID and date efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a reasonably large dataframe (70k by 900) which contains and ID, a date and ~900 code columns. The codes are missing in places and I am trying to fill in these missing values.

The rule is, for each ID which contains a code not recorded in later dates, it should be carried forward.

I have converted my dataframe to wide format (assuming this is easiest way to carry values down).

See example df:

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(
id = c('p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2'),
date = as.Date(1:6, origin=Sys.Date()),
code_1 = c('c_1', NA, NA, 'c_1', NA, NA),
code_2 = c(NA, 'c_2', NA, NA, NA, NA),
code_3 = c(NA, NA, 'c_3', NA, NA, NA)))
```

I would like to return something like the following, where codes are successively filled:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(list(
id = c('p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2'),
date = as.Date(1:6, origin=Sys.Date()),
code_1 = c('c_1', 'c_1', 'c_1', 'c_1', 'c_1', 'c_1'),
code_2 = c(NA, 'c_2', 'c_2', NA, NA, NA),
code_3 = c(NA, NA, 'c_3', NA, NA, NA)))
```

I have tried the following:

```
df[, lapply(FUN = na.locf, na.rm = FALSE), by = .(id)]
```

However due to the size, my computer is unable to process this, therefore the solution has to be efficient.

Would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Are the codes unique for each id, i.e. once p1 has c_1 in code_1 can it have a different code in code_1 later?

Comment: You are trying to use `data.table`-syntax on a dataframe, which won't work. Using `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, 3:5 := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE), by = id, .SDcols = 3:5][]` should do the job.

Comment: @kath Thanks for your comment. The codes are not unique for each id, however given the construct of the dataframe, only code_1 will appear in code_1 column. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for your answer. Apologies, the original df is a data.table - I'm trying the solution now... It's taking quite awhile to run, i'll let you know if it works - thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(code_1:code_3)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
      id       date code_1 code_2 code_3
  <fctr>     <date> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1     p1 2017-10-17    c_1     NA     NA
2     p1 2017-10-18    c_1    c_2     NA
3     p1 2017-10-19    c_1    c_2    c_3
4     p2 2017-10-20    c_1     NA     NA
5     p2 2017-10-21    c_1     NA     NA
6     p2 2017-10-22    c_1     NA     NA
```

Comment: Great solution, this worked perfectly. Has the added incumbent benefit of a progress bar (the data is massive so this is helpful). Thank you!